# In Java, what's the best way to make class A do something when an event happens in class B without class B knowing of class A's existence?

Tags: java, relationship

I'm making a little game and I have a PlayScreen, which has a GameWorld, which has a Player. Now whenever Player touches a teleport block, I dim the PlayScreen, then Player teleports and then the PlayScreen brightens back up again.

Currently to achieve this I added a `boolean inTeleportAnimation` to Player. Then PlayScreen checks every single frame inside `update()` if Player is in teleport animation and if so, it starts dimming the screen. Now this seems fine because it only checks for 1 boolean/trigger. But later there might be A LOT of different triggers for the PlayScreen to do something (e.g. dim the screen). It's probably a bad idea to have `playScreen.update()` check for every single trigger/boolean every frame as it would mean I need another if statement for every possible trigger. I don't want to make PlayScreen and Player's relation bidirectional either.

What would be the best or "correct" way to achieve this?

Comment: Observer pattern maybe?

Comment: [Publish-Subscribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern. Actually, observer is probably better in your case at this point.

Comment: Then in this case the Player would be the observable, correct? But PlayScreen is the main game loop class and it basically updates the whole GameWorld every frame, so it also updates Player. if I make Player the observable and PlayScreen the observer, this would essentially create a bidirectional relationship. Not sure if I'm missing something, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make use of the [observer design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to solve this task. It should solve your problem of wanting to avoid a bidirectional coupling, because the PlayScreen (the observer in this case) would be notified of the changes to the Player (the observable in this case) as needed, but would otherwise have no reference to, or any other type of tight coupling to the Player.

If you're using Java, as the tags for this post indicate, here is a [simple example in Java](https://www.concretepage.com/java/example-observer-observable-java) that should serve to demonstrate its use.

Comment: So using this pattern, the observable has instances of it's observers, but the observers also update the observable in their update(Observable obs) method? Where do the observers get the observable from? Sorry I'm new to this pattern so I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: As a sidenote, would it be bad practice for there to be a static class PlayScreenDimmer with a static instance of PlayScreen so I could dim PlayScreen from anywhere?

Comment: The observable would contain no reference to any instance of its observers within its class definition. The only (loosely coupled) association occurs with the call to (see referenced example) Observable#addObserver. This creates a collection of observers (PlayScreen, or whatever else you add that implements the Observer interface) who are interested in receiving updates (via the Observer#update method) which are published by the observable Player (via the Observable#notifyObservers method).

Comment: As to your side note question, why not just add a non-static #dim method to your PlayScreen class that is called when an update is received via your Observer#update method?

Comment: Okay thanks, I will do a bit more research on how to implement this pattern. Yeah the static PlayScreenDimmer was more of a alternative to the observer pattern. Of course using the observer pattern I wouldn't need any static methods.

Comment: Another issue that I find with this, is that everything in the GameWorld should update before any rendering happens. But if Player notifies PlayScreen that the screen should dim, then it will dim before everything else in the GameWorld has been updated and I try to make sure everything updates before any rendering happens.. It could notify PlayScreen by simply setting a flag and then once the rendering starts, it dims. But then I face the same issue where I will have to set tons of flags for every event that may trigger a PlayScreen change and I will have to check for all of these.

Comment: If I were faced with that issue, I'd set a "dirty" boolean flag inside each observer instead of updating the screen as soon as the update is received. That way, when it comes time to do a screen render, you can simply loop through all of the observers and, if the observer's dirty flag is true, you can do the update for that observer along with all the others within a negligible space of time.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can also pass ANY type of object to the Observable#notifyObservers method. You could make the object something that encapsulates all kinds of information about what each observer is supposed to do. It could have a "command" field that says if the notification simply indicates that the player touched something, or it could be a command to tell each observer that it's time to do it's part in the render cycle. In the latter case, all observers could be told this simultaneously. Hence, no need to litter your code with a million types of different global flags.

Comment: What about a PlayerState object and whenever player does something, it notifies the PlayScreen by altering the PlayerState with a State enum. Let's say State.IDLE or State.TELEPORT. And then once the rendering part of PlayScreen happens, it starts a switch case. In case of State.IDLE it will simply do nothing, but in case of State.TELEPORT, it will start dimming the screen. Is this similar to what you meant or am I getting it wrong? Is it best to do the switch case and dimscreen logic inside the PlayerState object or inside PlayScreen?

Comment: The player's state should be maintained within the Player object. How familiar are you with object-oriented programming concepts? I'd recommend you study up on it as it may really help with what you're trying to achieve. What about a State enum inside of the Player object? As for the other part of your strategy, I'm afraid I'm starting to get a bit lost :)

Comment: If you want to wait until a certain interval to render a bunch of stuff based upon the state change of multiple numbers of objects, you can just maintain a collection of all such objects. When you want to render, you could loop through all of them and if their state has changed, each can contribute its change to the render for that particular interval.

Comment: I think your last comment is what I will do. I am familiar with OOP and I understand that all information about Player should probably be stored inside Player itself. But the observer pattern had me a bit confused as I thought Player/observable "notifies" the PlayScreen/observer about it's state, upon which the observer will act. This seemed like the best way to go about achieving that. But I guess saving the State inside Player and then looping through it in PlayScreen's render() is just as easy. My mind was too set on using an observer pattern and I didn't consider other ways to use a state.

Comment: Anyways, thanks for your detailed input and opinion, definitely useful.

Comment: Understood :) Keep in mind that, under the hood, an Observable maintains a collection of its Observer's. You could rely on this and send info to each observer via whatever type of (possibly complex) object you wish. So you could use this, or you could maintain your own collection. And yes, it's best to understand design patterns and use them where applicable, but not be bound and restricted by them. Think of them as more of guidelines than hard rules.

Comment: And you are welcome! Good luck with what you're trying to achieve. I'd be interested to hear how it turns out!

Answer (score 0):

What if your player sets a global flag that gets turned on whenever an update happens in Player (for ex, when inTeleportAnimation is set this flag also gets set, same for other flags) and which is turned off after PlayScreen.update() handles an update, that way Player does not know about PlayScreen and you can avoid unnecessary checks in each frame. But I don't see a way to avoid the checks for each condition (assuming the global flag indicates an update).

Comment: So you basically mean 2 flags, 1 that notifies that an event has happened and then the PlayScreen can find the other one that specifies which event happened? This is what I thought of as well, but I'm not sure if this is bad practice..

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant and in this case the relationship is one way. Having the global flag is just more of a performance optimization.